# Extrema of a functional given weak and weak lower semicontinuity

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Assume $X$ is Hilbert space and let $\bar B_r=\{u \in E: \|u\|\le r\}$. Also, Let $J \in C(X, \mathbb{R})$
I want to show that if $J$ is weak lower semi continuous then there exist a $z$ in $\bar B_r$ which minimizes the functional.

$X$ must be reflexive since it is a Hilbert space. We also have boundedness of the functional from weak lower semi continuity, so coercivity is not needed. The conditions of Weierstrass theorem are therefore satisfied and $J$ has a minimum.

Next, I want to show that if $J$ is weakly continuous then there exist a $z \in \bar B_r$ that maximizes $J(z)$.
If we can show that $-J(z)$ is a minimum then this will be enough to conclude.
Now weak continuity implies boundedness and again, $X$ is reflexive. But I don't have weak lower semicontinuity so how do I show the existence of a maximum?

Am I  on the right track for the first part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part is correct. Let $x_n$ be such that $f(x_n) <m+\frac  1 n$ where $m$ is the infimum of $f$ on $\overline {B_r}$. If $x$ is a limit point of $(x_n)$ in the weakly compact set $\overline {B_r}$ then weak lower-semi continuity gives $f(x) \leq m$. But $m \leq f(x)$ so $f(x)=m$.

If $J$  is weakly continuous then so is $-J$ which implies that $-J$ is weakly (upper and) lower semi continuous. Hence, $-J$ attains its minimum which means $J$ attains its maximum on $\overline {B_r}$.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're doing here. I'm assuming part b. I don't have lower semi continuity here however

Comment: @Jama I have edited my answer.

Comment: ok thats what I thought. I should be more confident